# Onion Architecture

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-4, repository, hibernate

After doing a whole bunch of research on Onion Architecture, I have made an attempt at implementing this in a new system that we are developing.

We have the Layers as per below:

- Domain

  - `Domain.Entities`
  - `Domain.Interfaces`
- Infrastructure

  - `Infrastructure.Data`
  - `Infrastructure.DependencyResolution`
  - `Infrastructure.Interfaces`
  - `Infrastructure.Logging`
- Services

  - `Services.Interfaces`
- Tests

  - `Tests.Core`
- Web

  - `Web.UI`

**Domain.Entities - All the domain models are kept here.**

Base Entity

```
 namespace Domain.Entities
 {
    public class BaseEntity
    {
        public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }

        public virtual DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        public virtual DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; } 

        public override bool Equals (object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return false;  
            var t = obj as BaseEntity;  
            if (t == null)
                return false;  
            if (ID == t.ID)
                return true;  
            return false;  
        }

        public override int GetHashCode ()
        {
            int hash = GetType ().GetHashCode ();
            hash = (hash * 397) ^ ID.GetHashCode ();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Company Entity

```
namespace Domain.Entities
{
    public class Company : BaseEntity
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<Branch> Branches { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<Department> Departments { get; set; }

        public class CompanyCollection : List<Company>
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Domain.Interfaces - I have a bunch of generic interfaces programmed here.**

- `IReadRepository`
- `IReadWriteRepsitory`
- `IUnitOfWork`
- `IWriteRepository`

**`IReadRepository`**

```
namespace Domain.Interfaces
{
    public interface IReadRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> All ();

        TEntity FindBy (Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression);

        TEntity FindBy (object id);

        IQueryable<TEntity> FilterBy (Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression);
    }
}
```

**`IWriteRepository`**

```
namespace Domain.Interfaces
{
    public interface IWriteRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        bool Add (TEntity entity);

        bool Add (IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);

        bool Update (TEntity entity);

        bool Update (IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);

        bool Delete (TEntity entity);

        bool Delete (IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
    }
}
```

**`IReadWriteRepository`**

```
namespace Domain.Interfaces
{
    public interface IReadWriteRepository<TEntity> : 
                        IReadRepository<TEntity>, IWriteRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {

    }
}
```

**`IUnitOfWork`**

```
namespace Domain.Interfaces
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        void Commit ();

        void Rollback ();
    }
}
```

**`Infrastructure.Interfaces` - Store all infrastructure service interfaces here**

```
namespace Infrastructure.Interfaces
{
    public interface IConfigService
    {
        string Connection{ get; }
    }
}

namespace Infrastructure.Interfaces
{
    public interface ILoggingService
    {
        bool IsDebugEnabled { get; }

        bool IsErrorEnabled { get; }

        bool IsFatalEnabled { get; }

        bool IsInfoEnabled { get; }

        bool IsTraceEnabled { get; }

        bool IsWarnEnabled { get; }

        void Debug (Exception exception);

        void Debug (string format, params object[] args);

        void Debug (Exception exception, string format, params object[] args);

        void Error (Exception exception);

        void Error (string format, params object[] args);

        void Error (Exception exception, string format, params object[] args);

        void Fatal (Exception exception);

        void Fatal (string format, params object[] args);

        void Fatal (Exception exception, string format, params object[] args);

        void Info (Exception exception);

        void Info (string format, params object[] args);

        void Info (Exception exception, string format, params object[] args);

        void Trace (Exception exception);

        void Trace (string format, params object[] args);

        void Trace (Exception exception, string format, params object[] args);

        void Warn (Exception exception);

        void Warn (string format, params object[] args);

        void Warn (Exception exception, string format, params object[] args);
    }
}
```

**`Infrastructure.Data` - I'm using Fluent NHibernate to talk to a postgresql database.**

In here I keep my Mapping Files, Unit of work implementation and the Generic repository implementation.

**Hibernate Helper**

```
namespace Infrastructure.Data.Helpers
{
    public class NHibernateHelper
    {
        private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
        private readonly string _connectionString;

        public NHibernateHelper (string connectionString)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (connectionString))
                throw new HibernateConfigException ("ConnectionString in Web.config is not set.");

            _connectionString = connectionString;
        }

        public ISessionFactory SessionFactory {
            get {
                return _sessionFactory ?? (_sessionFactory = InitializeSessionFactory ());
            }
        }

        private ISessionFactory InitializeSessionFactory ()
        {
            return Fluently.Configure () . . . . . . .;
        }
    }

}
```

**Unit Of Work**

```
namespace Infrastructure.Data.Helpers
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
        private readonly ITransaction _transaction;

        public ISession Session { get; private set; }

        public UnitOfWork (ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
        {
            _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
            Session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession ();
            Session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Auto;
            _transaction = Session.BeginTransaction (IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        }

        public void Commit ()
        {
            if (!_transaction.IsActive) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException ("Oops! We don't have an active transaction");
            }
            _transaction.Commit ();
        }

        public void Rollback ()
        {
            if (_transaction.IsActive) {
                _transaction.Rollback ();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose ()
        {
            if (Session.IsOpen) {
                Session.Close ();
                Session = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Base Mapping**

```
namespace Infrastructure.Data.Mapping
{
    public class BaseMapping : ClassMap<BaseEntity>
    {
        public BaseMapping ()
        {
            UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping ();
            Id (x => x.ID);
            Map (x => x.DateCreated);
            Map (x => x.DeletedDate);
        }
    }
}
```

**Company Mapping**

```
namespace Infrastructure.Data.Mapping
{
    public class CompanyMapping : SubclassMap<Company>
    {
        public CompanyMapping ()
        {
            Abstract ();
            Map (x => x.Name);

            HasManyToMany<User> (x => x.Users).Table ("CompanyUser").Inverse ();

            HasMany<Branch> (x => x.Branches).Inverse ().Cascade.All ();
            HasMany<Department> (x => x.Departments).Inverse ().Cascade.All ();

            Table ("Company");
        }
    }
}
```

**Repository Implementation**

```
namespace Infrastructure.Data.Repositories
{
    public class Repository<TEntity> : IReadWriteRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class
    {
        private readonly ISession _session;

        public Repository (ISession session)
        {
            _session = session;
        }

        #region IWriteRepository

        public bool Add (TEntity entity)
        {
            _session.Save (entity);
            return true;
        }

        public bool Add (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            foreach (TEntity entity in entities) {
                _session.Save (entity);
            }
            return true;
        }

        public bool Update (TEntity entity)
        {
            _session.Update (entity);
            return true;
        }

        public bool Update (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            foreach (TEntity entity in entities) {
                _session.Update (entity);
            }
            return true;
        }

        public bool Delete (TEntity entity)
        {
            _session.Delete (entity);
            return true;
        }

        public bool Delete (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            foreach (TEntity entity in entities) {
                _session.Delete (entity);
            }
            return true;
        }

        #endregion

        #region IReadRepository

        public System.Linq.IQueryable<TEntity> All ()
        {
            return _session.Query<TEntity> ();
        }

        public TEntity FindBy (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
        {
            return FilterBy (expression).SingleOrDefault ();
        }

        public TEntity FindBy (object id)
        {
            return _session.Get<TEntity> (id);
        }

        public System.Linq.IQueryable<TEntity> FilterBy (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
        {
            return All ().Where (expression).AsQueryable ();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Finally, the service for dependency injection:

```
namespace Infrastructure.Data.Services
{
    public class ConfigService : IConfigService
    {
        #region IConfigService implementation

        public string Connection {
            get {
                string strConnectionString = null;
                var connectionSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["Connection"];

                if (connectionSettings != null) {
                    strConnectionString = connectionSettings.ConnectionString;
                }

                return strConnectionString;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**`Infrastructure.DependencyResolution` - Using Simple Injector**

In here I store all my registration packages / modules

ConfigPackage

```
namespace Infrastructure.DependecyResolution
{
    public class ConfigPackage : IPackage
    {
        #region IPackage implementation

        public void RegisterServices (SimpleInjector.Container container)
        {
            container.Register<IConfigService,ConfigService> ();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**`RepositoryPackage`**

```
namespace Infrastructure.DependecyResolution
{
    public class RepositoryPackage : IPackage
    {
        #region IPackage implementation

        public void RegisterServices (SimpleInjector.Container container)
        {

            container.RegisterPerWebRequest<ISessionFactory> (() => {

                var configPackage = container.GetInstance<IConfigService> ();
                NHibernateHelper objNHibernate = new NHibernateHelper (configPackage.Connection);
                return objNHibernate.SessionFactory;
            });

            container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork> ();

            container.RegisterPerWebRequest<ISession> (() => {

                UnitOfWork unitOfWork = (UnitOfWork)container.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork> ();
                return unitOfWork.Session;

            });

            container.RegisterOpenGeneric (typeof(IReadWriteRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**`LoggingPackage`**

```
namespace Infrastructure.DependecyResolution
{
    public class LoggingPackage : IPackage
    {
        #region IPackage implementation

        public void RegisterServices (SimpleInjector.Container container)
        {
            ILoggingService logger = GetLoggingService ();

            container.Register<ILoggingService> (() => logger);
        }

        #endregion

        private ILoggingService GetLoggingService ()
        {
            ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.LayoutRenderers.RegisterDefinition ("utc_date", typeof(UtcDateRenderer));
            ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.LayoutRenderers.RegisterDefinition ("web_variables", typeof(WebVariablesRenderer));

            ILoggingService logger = (ILoggingService)LogManager.GetLogger ("NLogLogger", typeof(LoggingService));

            return logger;
        }
    }
}
```

**`Infrastructure.Logging` - using NLog**

In here is just the implementation of the logging interface.

**`Services.Interfaces` - Applicaiton Service interfaces gets stored here**

```
namespace Services.Interfaces
{
    public interface ICompanyService
    {
        IQueryable<Company> GetCompanies ();

        Company GetCompany (Guid guidId);

        void CreateNewCompany (Company company);

        void UpdateExistingCompany (Company company);

        void DeleteCompany (Company company);
    }
}
```

**`Tests.Core`**

Repository and Service Tests are in here at this stage, sure there will be more tests going in here.

**`Web.UI` - ASP.NET MVC 4 Project as user interface application**

Implementation of the Company Service Interface.

```
namespace Web.UI.Services
{
    public class CompanyService : ICompanyService
    {
        private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private IReadWriteRepository<Company> _companyRepository;

        public CompanyService (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IReadWriteRepository<Company> companyRepository)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _companyRepository = companyRepository;
        }

        #region ICompanyService implementation

        public IQueryable<Company> GetCompanies ()
        {
            return _companyRepository.All ().Where (x => !x.DeletedDate.HasValue);
        }

        public Company GetCompany (Guid guidId)
        {
            return _companyRepository.FindBy (guidId);
        }

        public void CreateNewCompany (Company company)
        {
            if (_companyRepository.Add (company))
                _unitOfWork.Commit ();
            else
                _unitOfWork.Rollback ();
        }

        public void UpdateExistingCompany (Company company)
        {
            if (_companyRepository.Update (company))
                _unitOfWork.Commit ();
            else
                _unitOfWork.Rollback ();
        }

        public void DeleteCompany (Company company)
        {
            if (_companyRepository.Update (company))
                _unitOfWork.Commit ();
            else
                _unitOfWork.Rollback ();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

The Inject the `ICompanyService` into the Controller. Create a view model for Company which the view can manipulate.

Simple Injector Service also gets initialized in this project. While it gets initialized I register the Services.Interfaces to `Web.UI.Services` implementation.

That is pretty much how I have implemented the Onion Architecture. Let me know if I went wrong somewhere. This is the first time I set up an application with a proper architecture.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Let me know if I went wrong somewhere. This is the first time I set up an application with a proper architecture.

I'm afraid there is no such thing as general "proper" architecture. Relevant architecture is the one that enables/assists developers in implementing new functionality or adjusting your solution to new requirements.

In your implementation I don't see the reason to define your own logging and repository/UoW patterns:

- logging - there is NLog/log4net/whatever, why abstract from them? Even if you may want to switch the implementation, use `Common.Logging`. All these frameworks do not (and should not) use dependency injection, so having `ILoggingService` injected will only make your life harder.
- repository/UnitOfWork pattern - It's a long-running discussion between those who think repository is a must, and those who see it as a redundant layer that only makes your life harder, and leads to leaked abstractions in all but most simple scenarios. I'm in the latter camp, so here are a couple of links from one of the NHibernate core devs:

  - [Repository is the new Singleton](http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton)
  - [Refactoring toward frictionless & odorless code: The baseline](http://ayende.com/blog/4803/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-the-baseline)
  - [Refactoring toward frictionless & odorless code: Hiding global state](http://ayende.com/blog/4804/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-hiding-global-state)
  - [Refactoring toward frictionless & odorless code: Limiting session scope](http://ayende.com/blog/4805/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-limiting-session-scope)
  - [Refactoring toward frictionless & odorless code: A broken home (controller)](http://ayende.com/blog/4806/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-a-broken-home-controller)
  - [Refactoring toward frictionless & odorless code: The case for the view model](http://ayende.com/blog/4807/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-the-case-for-the-view-model)
  - [Refactoring toward frictionless & odorless code: Getting rid of globals](http://ayende.com/blog/4808/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-getting-rid-of-globals)
  - [Refactoring toward frictionless & odorless code: What about transactions?](http://ayende.com/blog/4809/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-what-about-transactions)

Note that the series of articles "Refactoring toward frictionless & odorless code" actually show how you can move the transaction/session management to infrastructure level, leaving your business logic clean an tidy.

And a couple of small comments:

- I don't see any reason to have `public class CompanyCollection : List<Company> {}`
- `Repository` - why do you `return true` in `Update` methods? If there is a failure - throw exception, not `return false`.
- `IConfigService`/`ConfigService` breaks Open/Closed principle, as would need to edit this class (add properties) whenever a new configuration parameter is needed. Classes that require configuration should expect specific configuration values in constructor instead of consuming the general `IConfigService`. Inject these parameters at the DI registration time. If you need a dynamic configuration which can be changed during software execution - then some sort of `IConfigService` can be implemented, but I would suggest to have a general `T GetValue<T>(string configName)` in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, exactly what I was looking for. I will go read and improve the solution.

Comment: Just a point about the logging... `Common.Logging`, being the 'common interface' that it is, makes you lose a lot of the power you can get from individual logging frameworks, e.g. logging custom fields. In my experience I've found it to be more of a hindrance than a help.

Comment: @Gigi - Agree. We use `Common.Logging` when developing frameworks that may be used in other projects, in order not to force specific logging infrastructure

Comment: @almaz about the logging... what do you mean by "All these frameworks do not (and should not) use dependency injection"? Where is the problem of using logging interface and just inject implementation via `IoC`? I think abstracting logging class is a very good practice and you can see it in almost every `IoC` tutorial/article. Can you point out what problems did you have with such solution?

Comment: @voytek Look at recommended approach in common.logging, log4net or nlog logging frameworks. All of them suggest to have a logger specific to each class via `LogManager.GetLogger` (or `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger`) by capturing logger instance in a static readonly field

Comment: @almaz so, you're saying to declare private static readonly object in EVERY class? like this: `private static readonly ILog logger =  LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SampleClass)); ` and then call it: `logger.Debug("foo");`?

I have to say I once read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5646876/4945059) answer and since then I always create a wrapper and inject logger via `IoC` (of course I'm talking about bigger projects)

Comment: @voytek yes, in every class where you want to use the logging infrastructure. And it is done like that for purpose: you may have different loggers in different classes, depending on logging configuration defined in configuration file (or in code). E.g. you may want to log all the tracing details from `YourNamespace.MyClass` class, but suppress everything but errors from everything else

Comment: @almaz Yes, But you are depending on specific logger provider (log4net, nlog, etc..), aren't you? I can use logger in the same way you wrote (using Steven solution from answer I showed you), the only reason I will inject provider I want. So, the difference is that, in your class you have one object more and I have one parameter more. What did you mean by "recommended approach"? Can you point me out link with such recommendations?

Comment: @voytek How often in your past experience you had to change the logging framework? How do you enable detailed logging for particular class or namespace, while logging only errors from everything else? Steven's solution provides the same instance of logger for every object. Which means that you're loosing significant part of functionality from logging frameworks.

Comment: @almaz one thing left that bothers me is SOLID's `Single Responsibility Principle`. Isn't this approach validating this principle? If you want to use different logger in specific class, you can just inject different logger.

Comment: @voytek There is no violation here. Single responsibility principle dictates that `every class should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software` (wikipedia). Firstly, logging is not a part of functionality, it is something that comes along to help make sure that functionality is correct. Secondly - you still delegate all the logging to the logging framework, so your class does not violate the single responsibility. And thirdly - all frameworks are meant to be used in a certain way. By trying to use them differently just makes the life much much harder

Comment: `why do you return true in Update methods? If there is a failure - throw exception, not return false` It's my understanding that exceptions as a method of flow control leads to some nasty smells?

Comment: Look at the original code, it just returns true without any additional logic. Regarding your comment on "flow control" - it depends on the definition of what you define as "business flow" and what is "exceptional flow". My opinion (and most, if not all, ORMs follow it) is that the inability to apply changes to the data store is an exceptional flow, thus it should be handled via exceptions